# Code works as expected in debugging mode but when I started it in normal run, it fails

Tags: python, node.js, pipe

I'm writing an application in Node.JS that uses an SMB3 protocol client written in Python. Node.JS is piped into Python code. When I execute the application in debugging and resume program slowly in certain lines, it works normally. Whenever I press run, it will freeze the gauge positioned in the UI representing the loaded data so far. What might be the source problem? I suspect GIL in Python. What do you think? It is as if it is loaded by so many requests from Node.JS, that it cannot withstand incoming this many requests at once.

Comment: We really need a bit more context here.  My guess would be some sort of race condition in your code.